# With with Apache RegEx to Lighttpd

Tags: regex, apache, lighttpd

I just can't seem to get this one right.

```
RewriteRule !\.(z|js|ico|css|php)$ index.php [NC]
```

The developer (no longer here) put this in the Lighttpd config :

```
url.rewrite-once("^(/(?!( \.(z|js|ico|css|php)$)).*)" => "index.php")
```

But it doesn't seem to do the same thing. Any file requested that doesn't end in one of those extensions should be directed to index.php

I suspect the entire conversion was done wrong :

```
RewriteRule ^top$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^images/.* - [NC,L]

RewriteRule !\.(z|js|ico|css|php)$ index.php [NC]

RewriteRule .*/stats/.* index.php [NC]
```

Can anyone help me out? This guy left me in a lurch and I have next to zero experience with RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do, there was some stuff missing `.*` and an extra `^` (caret).

```
url.rewrite-once("(/(?!(.*.(z|js|ico|css|php)$)).*)" => "index.php")
```